# Can I Inherit a view of Asp.net mvc2 from normal asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

Can I Inherit a view in asp.net mvc2 from normal asp.net master page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can inherit the asp.net master page in view

Answer (score 1):

No, View can not be inherited in Asp.Net mvc. It is just a template.

Comment: My doubt is to inherit a asp.net master page in View